# How to determine the batchSize of the sinks in Flume?

Tags: flume, bigdata

I am setting the properties of a Flume Agent and I am not sure what value should I use for the batchSize (number of events to batch together for send).

In my particular case I will use the console as a sink. As I understand the logger-sink is the type used in this case. But Flume documentation doesn't mention the batchSize paramenter for this kind of sink. Isn't it necessary to define a batchSize for logger-sinks?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found an answer for the question: *Isn't it necessary to define a batchSize for logger-sinks?*

https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#logger-sink There is not batchSize, instead there is a parameter calle **maxBytesToLog** which defines the maximum number of bytes of the Event body to log (by default its value is 16). Here there is simple example I found of a Flume Agent which uses the console as sink:

```
node.sources = my-source
node.channels = my-channel
node.sinks = my-sink
# Since node 1 sink is avro-type, here we indicate avro as source type
node.sources.my-source.type = avro
node.sources.my-source.bind = 0.0.0.0
node.sources.my-source.port = 11112
node.sources.my-source.channels = my-channel
node.channels.my-channel.type = memory
node.channels.my-channel.capacity = 10000
node.channels.my-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
node.sinks.my-sink.type = logger
node.sinks.my-sink.channel = my-channel
node.sinks.my-sink.maxBytesToLog = 256
```

Source from: https://medium.com/@DCA/something-about-flume-3cb720ba00e8#.37zs23dnt

And about the main question **How to determine the batchSize of the sink**?

With regards to the hdfs batch size, the larger your batch size the better performance will be. However, keep in mind that if a transaction fails the entire transaction will be replayed which could have the implication of duplicate events downstream.

From:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLUME/BatchSize,+ChannelCapacity+and+ChannelTransactionCapacity+Properties